# angularjs app.run doesn't get called with state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I can't see the problem at all, here's my code.

```
var app = angular.module('application', ['ui.router', 'ngResource','user.controllers','user.services']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html'

  }).state('account', {
    url: '/account',
    templateUrl: 'views/user/account.html',
    controller: 'UserCtrl'

  }).state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'views/user/login.html',
    controller: 'UserCtrl'

  }).state('logout', {
    url: '/logout',
    templateUrl: 'views/user/logout.html',
    controller: 'UserCtrl'

  }).state('register', {
    url: '/register',
    templateUrl: 'views/user/register.html',
    controller: 'UserCtrl'
  });
});


app.run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    console.log('toState.name: ' + toState.name);
    console.log('fromState.name: ' + fromState.name)
  });
});
```

It seems pretty straightforward to do, but it just doesn't work. I'm sure it's a little thing I don't know about Angular, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you posted, it looks like you're missing a closing `})` at the end of your `$stateProvider.state` declaration.

---

**UPDATE:**

[DEMO EXAMPLE (Plunker)](http://plnkr.co/edit/QxdL0jfUHE6q3cfPXaBk?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer, but it was a copy-paste error, I edited my entry.

Comment: Do you know why when I add event.preventDefault(); and $state.go('login'); inside $rootScope.$on, it doesn't go to the login state?

Comment: Put the `$state.go('login');` before the `event.preventDefault();` and it should work