# Why does $state.transitionTo or $state.go does not display the new HTML partial?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here is a piece of code destined to check user rights before each UI-router state change. Everything works fine, except the fact that when rights are OK, the transition to the new state (either with $state.go, as below, or with $state.transitionTo), does not seem to do anything at all (the console message is logged but that's all).

```
angular.module('mymodule', [ /* dependancies */ ])

.run( function($rootScope, $window, $state, AuthManager)
{
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
        function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams)
        {
            if( ! S.isUserConnected() && toParams.requiresLogIn )
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                AuthManager.openConnectionPane().then( function( data )
                {
                    if( AuthManager.isUserConnected() ) {
                        console.log("This message is correctly printed!");
                        $state.go( toState.name );
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Do you have any idea why this does not work?

**EDIT:**

I have noticed that the HMTL partial coresponding to the state we are transitioning to, is correctly fetched via a GET request, but it never shows: the old HTML stays displayed (the one from the previous state), even if the URL is correctly updated...

**EDIT: add the router config code**

In the main module file:

```
//angular.module('mymodule', [ /* dependancies */ ])
.config( $urlRouterProvider ) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
}
```

And in each submodule:

```
angular.module( 'mymodule.submodule', [ /* dependancies */ ])

.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('events-overview', {
            url:'/events',
            templateUrl: 'app/events/events-overview.html',
            controller: 'EventsOverviewCtrl'
        })
        .state('events-details', {
            url:'/events/{eventId:int}',
            templateUrl: 'app/events/events-details.html',
            controller: 'EventsDetailsCtrl'
        })
        .state('events-creation', {
            url:'/events/new',
            params: {
                requiresLogIn: true
            }
            templateUrl: 'app/events/events-creation.html',
            controller: 'EventsCreationCtrl'
        })
});
```

Comment: probably something wrong with your state config. can you show me where you set it up using the $stateprovider

Comment: no error logged in the console?

Comment: @Silverspur what is in your example toState.name

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe: no error logged.

Comment: @Arno_Geismar: it is the target state name (cf. here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events). Having tested it with a log (that is not in the above code), it has correct values, such as 'events-creation' for instance (without the quotes).

Comment: @Silverspur yeah I know what it does just wondering if it had the correct state names

Comment: @Arno_Geismar: I guessed you did, but just wanted to be sure :) And yes, the state names seem to be correct...

Comment: Hi @Silverspur,
Due to the characters limit in the comment, I've moved this bellow, to the answer section. Check it out please.

Comment: Haven't had the time to try it out, but I found this [$urlRouter.sync()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#urlroutersync) This could perhaps be useful

Comment: `AuthManager.openConnectionPane()` method does return a promise using `$q`/`$resource`/`$http`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and this is how I solved it:

```
if( AuthManager.isUserConnected() ) {
   //...
   event.preventDefault();
   $state.go(toState.name, null, {notify: false}).then(function (state) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('$stateChangeSuccess', state, null);
   });
}
```

As it's mentioned in other answers, `$state.go` doesn't work propertly in `.run`. Following the advises of [this thread](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2098) I ended up working with this workaround

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector) {
   var $state = $injector.get('$state');
   $state.go('/home');
});
```

Not sure if this could help you, but you could try it. Hope it helps

Comment: Just tested the first piece of code, this works! Thanks! For the second issue you're mentionning, I had already solved it by limiting the tests to states **other than 'home'**, to prevent the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem will be fixed by doing this :

```
angular.module('mymodule', [ /* dependancies */ ])

.run( function($rootScope, $window, $state, AuthManager, $timeout)
{
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
        function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams)
        {
            if( ! S.isUserConnected() && toParams.requiresLogIn )
            {

                AuthManager.openConnectionPane().then( function( data )
                {
                    if( AuthManager.isUserConnected() ) {
                        console.log("This message is correctly printed!");
                         $timeout(function() {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $state.go(toState.name);
                          });

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    );
});
```

$state.go does not work correctly in `.run` this should be a workaround by adding the timeout

Comment: Just tested that, but the issue stays the same. I actually noticed that the HMTL partial coresponding to the state we are transitioning to is fetched via a GET request, but it never shows (I updated the question).

Answer (score 0):

try putting the `event.preventDefault();` bellow the `$state.go`.

This is where I saw the idea for this suggestion:
[angularjs app.run doesn't get called with state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657127/angularjs-app-run-doesnt-get-called-with-state)

So basically:

`AuthManager.openConnectionPane().then( function( data ) {
    if( AuthManager.isUserConnected() ) {
      console.log("This message is correctly printed!");
      $state.go( toState.name );
    }
});
event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Sorry for not providing the working solution, and GJ @troig :)