# cannot forward to another page in change route event ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my application I am trying to redirect the user to get redirected to login if he is not logged in and if he is than restrict him from visiting login page And I implemented the same like this before as well but now its not working I would like to know what I am doing wrong

```
  app.run(function ($rootScope, $state,    authService) {
         $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams,   fromState, fromParams) {
            if (toState === 'home' && authService.isAuthenticated()) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go(fromState);
            }
            if (toState !== 'home' && !authService.isAuthenticated()) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go('home');
            }

        });
    });
```

I have done same here as well but it was working I don't know why that was working and this is not working.

[The link for the code that was working](https://github.com/yashdeeph709/roomersClient/blob/master/client/src/main/webapp/js/app.js)

Comment: do you get any error in console? Have you checked if the stateChangeStart function is getting called when you change state

Comment: yup its getting called and when I am doing $state.go again its again getting called and here the stack goes overflow so what can I do

Comment: Hey I got the solution the Fromstate is an object which is having key name that should be used in conditions but thanks for help

Comment: $state.go doesn't work propertly in `.run`. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31850431/why-does-state-transitionto-or-state-go-does-not-display-the-new-html-partial), I think the answers could help you