# Use $state.current in .run

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-services

I have this code in a Angular Service

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) { 
            if (storageService.getValue("login_credentials") && (storageService.getValue("auto_login"))) {
                httpService.doLogin(function (){
                    if (!toState.data.require_authentication) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                    if (!checkStorageIntegrity(toState.data)) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $state.go("page.login");
                        return;
                    }
                    validate(function (data) {
                        if (!data.fn.result.done) {
                            $state.go("page.login");
                        }
                        storageService.setKey("auto_login", false);
                    });
                });
            }
```

but i want to move httpService.doLogin({....}) in .run and i don't have tostate. if i use $state.current give me `{name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true}`. How can i get the current state?

Comment: Well in my cases the $state.current have allways been empty inside javascript code, though ive used it in view-s... But maybe you could try $location.path().. it will give you the url, since you only check for string value you might just check the url

Comment: @MaanusIndov thanks for response. But for me, 
It is not a pretty solution.

Comment: well i tryed out this, and in run it has toState.name
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657127/angularjs-app-run-doesnt-get-called-with-state

Comment: @MaanusIndov 
I do not need to use $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart' in .run. I want to know only current state (without tostate).